# Format a number stored as a String

Tags: java, string, number-formatting

I have a `String` that represents an amount of money passed from input that will optionally contain a decimal point and trailing zeros. It can look like any of these:

```
inputA = "123.45"
inputB = "123"
inputC = "123.4"
inputD = ".50"
```

Is there a way to convert these so that they all have the format `0.00` with at least one digit to the left of the decimal point and exactly two to the right without having to convert to a number object like BigDecimal and then back?

Comment: Nice!, share your code and tell us where you are stuck

Comment: Yes. But then you've rewritten the logic that Java already gives you. Is there something wrong with using a `double` and a `DecimalFormat`?

Comment: No, not really that was my backup plan. But I would rather not have to convert a `String` into a `double` and then back into a `String` if I can help it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DecimalFormat to achieve formatting.

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##0.00");
System.out.println(format.format(10));
```

Output : 10.00

Answer (score 0):

Tricks:

```
String formattedDouble=String.format("%.2f", Double.valueOf(strDouble));
```

And, `%.2f` will format your `double` as `1.00`, `0.20` or `5.21`. `Double.valueOf(strDouble)` convert your `String double` into a `double`.